# java Backpropagation Neural Network gives unexpected output

Tags: java, neural-network, backpropagation

I made my first Backpropagation Neural Network using 
[this](http://galaxy.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t/backprop.html) tutorial. I wanted to teach it simple logick gate: 0&0=1, 0&1=0, 1&0=0, 1&1=1. Suprisingly, it gives me weird [output](http://pastebin.com/DHLP5suv) that I don't understand at all. I can't tell why average error is always ~0.5, why cases when output1 is good becomes bad and what makes NaN output. The code is below:

```
package NeuralNetPackage;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static double N(double[] x, double[] w){                         //neuron (input, weights{w1, w2, w3,...})
            double l=0; //input
            double y = 0; //modified output
            double NMax = 1;
            int i = 0;

                    while(i < x.length){   //calculating output

                    l += x[i] * w[i];              
                    i++;
                    }
          //if(Double.isNaN(l)==true){ l = 0.1;}
            y = (2/(1 + Math.pow(Math.pow((1+l), 1/l), -NMax*l)))-1;
            if(Math.abs(y)> 20) y = 200;
            //System.out.println(l) ;      
            return y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

            int i = 0; //temporary variables
            int z = 0;
            int t = 0;
            double j = 0;
            int v = 0;


            int[] toLearn = {0,0,1  ,1,0,0   ,0,1,0   ,1,1,1}; //truth table to learn


            int ey1 =0;                     //expected output
            double LRate = 0.1; //learn rate
            int cx = 2; //input count
            double y1 = 0;  //input1
            int[] NInLayer = {3, 2, 1};  //Neurons in every layer
            int[] NInputs = {cx, NInLayer[0], NInLayer[1]}; //input count in every layer
            int NCount = NInLayer[0] + NInLayer[1] + NInLayer[2];  //Neuron count
            double[] w = new double[NInLayer[0] * NInputs[0] + NInLayer[1] * NInputs[1] + NInLayer[2] * NInputs[2]];    //Weights
            double[] NOutputs = new double[cx + NCount];  //Neuron uotputs
            double[] NErrors = new double[NCount];          //Neuron errors
            double maxError = 0.1d;  //max error of network
            double error = 200d;  //actual error
            double avError = 200d;          //average error
            List<Double> errorTab = new ArrayList<Double>();        //array with errors to calulate average error

            sc.close();

            Random fW = new Random(); 

                    while(i < (NInLayer[0] * NInputs[0] + NInLayer[1] * NInputs[1] + NInLayer[2] * NInputs[2])){    //random weights on start
                            w[i] = fW.nextDouble()/2;
                            i++;
                    }



                    int c = 0;
                    while(avError > maxError){              //whole network in this loop
                            i = 0;

                            if(c >= 4) c = 0;

                            NOutputs[0] = toLearn[c*3]+1;           //inputs from truth table
                            NOutputs[1] = toLearn[c*3+1]+1;
                            ey1 = toLearn[c*3+2];


                            while(i < NCount){
                                    int u = (int)((i - 0.0001)/2);          //layer in which specified neuron is(0-2)
                                    z = 0;
                                    double[] in = new double[NInputs[u]];  //inputs for specified neuron
                                    double[] inW = new double[NInputs[u]];  //weights for specified neuron

                                            while(z < NInputs[u]){                          //specified neuron's inputs calculation
                                                    if(u == 0) in[z] = NOutputs[z];
                                                    if(u == 1) in[z] = NOutputs[z+cx];
                                                    if(u == 2) in[z] = NOutputs[z+cx + NInLayer[0]];
                                                    z++;
                                            }

                                            z = 0;


                                            while(z < NInputs[u]){                          //specified neuron's weights calculation
                                                    if(u==0){ inW[z] = w[(NInputs[u]*i)+z];} //System.out.println("Waga neuronu "+i + " = "+ w[(NInputs[u]*i)+z]);}
                                                    else if(u==1){ inW[z] = w[(NInputs[u]*i)-z];} //System.out.println("Waga neuronu "+i + " = "+ w[(NInputs[u]*i)-z]);}
                                                    else if(u==2){ inW[z] = w[((NInLayer[0] * NInputs[0] + NInLayer[1] * NInputs[1])) + (NInputs[u]*(i - (NInLayer[0] + NInLayer[1])))+z];} //System.out.println("Waga neuronu "+i + " = "+w[((NInLayer[0] * NInputs[0] + NInLayer[1] * NInputs[1])) + (NInputs[u]*(i - (NInLayer[0] + NInLayer[1])))+z]);}
                                                    z++;
                                                    }

                                            NOutputs[i + cx] = N(in, inW);  //saving output from specified neuron

                                            i++;
                                    }



                            y1 = NOutputs[NOutputs.length - 1];  //calculating output                                 
                            error = ey1 - y1;      //calculating error
                            if(error < 0) errorTab.add(error * -1);
                            else errorTab.add(error);                                       
                            z = 0;
                            System.out.println("Actual error " + error);

                            j += errorTab.get(v);  
                            if(v >= 5){avError = j/errorTab.size(); errorTab.clear(); v = -1; j = 0;} /calculating average error

                            i = 0;
                                    while(i < NCount){                      //calculating new weights
                                            int u = (int)(((NCount - i - 1) - 0.0001)/2);
                                                    if(u == 2) NErrors[NCount - i - 1] = error;     //for last layer

                                                    else{                   //for rest of layers
                                                            int h = 0;
                                                            double v2 = 0;

                                                            while(h < NInLayer[u+1]){
                                                                    v2 += NErrors[NCount - (NInLayer[u+1] - h)]*w[((NCount - i)+6)+(h*3)];
                                                                    h++;
                                                            }
                                                    NErrors[NCount - i - 1] = v2;
                                                    }
                                            //System.out.println("Błąd neuronu " + (NCount - i) +" = "+ NErrors[NCount - i -1]);
                                            i++;
                                    }

                            i = 0;
                                    while(i < NCount){              //saving new weights(backpropagation)
                                            int h = 0;
                                            int u = (int)((i - 0.0001)/2);
                                                    while(h < NInputs[u]){
                                                            if(u==0) w[(NInputs[u]*i)+h] += LRate * NErrors[i] * ((2*Math.exp(NOutputs[h])/Math.sqrt(Math.exp(NOutputs[h])+1)));
                                                            else if(u==1) w[(NInputs[u]*i)-h] += LRate * NErrors[i] * ((2*Math.exp(NOutputs[NInLayer[0]-1 + h])/Math.sqrt(Math.exp(NOutputs[NInLayer[0]-1 + h])+1)));
                                                            else if(u==2) w[((NInLayer[0] * NInputs[0] + NInLayer[1] * NInputs[1])) + (NInputs[u]*(i - (NInLayer[0] + NInLayer[1])))+h] += LRate * NErrors[i] * ((2*Math.exp(NOutputs[NInLayer[0]+NInLayer[1]+ h])/Math.sqrt(Math.exp(NOutputs[NInLayer[0]+NInLayer[1]+ h])+1)));
                                                            h++;
                                                    }
                                            i++;
                                    }


                            System.out.println("Input1 = "+(NOutputs[0]-1));                     
                            System.out.println("Input2 = "+(NOutputs[1]-1));
                            System.out.println("Output1 = "+y1);
                            System.out.println("Expected_Output1 = "+ey1);
                            System.out.println("Average error is " + avError);
                            System.out.println("Run_count " + (t+1));
                            System.out.println("*********************************************");

                            t++;
                            v++;
                            c++;
                            if(t >= 20000) System.exit(0);         //stop app if it is working too long
            }
    }
}
```

I can't discover what is wrong with my code. I really need your help. Thank you.

Comment: The problem was that neuron's activation function should not be linear.